# WPF: Load Window from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, window

How can I create `Window` instance from XAML file? In directory are located different XAML files (custom windows). I need load necessary XAML and show it. Is exists method as `Window.LoadFromXAML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [XamlReader.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It returns the root of the corresponding object tree. In your case the instance of Window class.